# Update View with Backend, won't work

Tags: primefaces

Following issue, I want to update my front-end from my backing-bean.

View:

```
<p:layoutUnit id="center" position="center">
        <p:layout>
            <p:layoutUnit id="inner_north" position="north" size="100">
                <h:form id="fortschrittForm">
                    <h:panelGrid columns="10" id="fortschritt" cellspacing="7" title="Fortschritt" cellpadding="6">
                        <h:outputText value="Mails heruntergeladen:"/>
                        <p:graphicImage library="img" name="erfolg.png"
                            rendered="#{managedBean.mails}" />
                        <h:outputText value="Pdfs wurden gelesen:"/>
                        <p:graphicImage library="img" name="erfolg.png"
                            rendered="#{managedBean.pdfs}" />
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </h:form>
                [...]
```

Button:

```
   <p:commandButton value="Transition starten"  actionListener="#{managedBean.prozessablauf}" update=":formTabelle:formDetail:msg anzeigeRisiko"/>
```

Backend:

```
public void prozessablauf() {
    try {
emailHerunterladen();
mails = true;
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("fortschrittForm:fortschritt");

 } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

My problem is that

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("fortschrittForm:fortschritt");
```

is not firing. Just when the method is completely done, all icons are shown. But I want in particular to update the fortschrittForm.

Heres the code in from firebug:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4sXF.png)

Comment: Check that the Id is definitely "fortschrittForm:fortschritt" using the browser. Also try ":fortschrittForm:fortschritt". What happens if you use update=""fortschrittForm:fortschritt" on the button?

Comment: farrellmr: Both of them i have checked. If i click the button a long process start in the background. For example first i download mails with attachement from my email-account, after them i read the attachements and so on. So for each step (download attachement = DONE) i want to show a success icon on the view. For that, i need update my frontend through my backend

Comment: Is the call to update in the button causing problems - move the update section from the button to the update method? Also is the model definitely updated at this point?

Comment: As u can see in the above section of my Button, i doesen't call the id for my 'fortschrittForm' in the update attribute from my button. So the update is done by my backend, but not particular just all at once at the end of working

Comment: If it was me - Id remove them for a test, and also consider changing h:panelGrid to p:panelGrid to see if it performs differently

Comment: Have set a link to an image in the above code that shows firebug from firefox.

Comment: Also i have edit my code as u said farrellmr. Same problem, just at the end of the method all icons where shown.

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is that
>
> ```
> RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("fortschrittForm:fortschritt");
> ```
>
> is not firing.

You misunderstand the behavior of `RequestContext#update` method. It **does not trigger a seperate response**. It just provides a simple way to set which components to update within the current request at runtime instead of hardcoding it via the *update* attribute in the markup.

> Just when the method is completely done, all icons are shown.

This is the normal behavior.

Every change to the view on the client side has to be made with a request from the client side. This is how it works (unless you are using sockets or something like this). So to reflect updates from a long running or composite process on the server side, you have to poll for updates from the client as long as the process is running.

E.g. [`<p:poll />`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/poll.xhtml) is a very good candidate to go with and i would try something like this:

1. When requesting the start of the process on the client side, also start `<p:poll />` with *update* attribute set to the target part of the view.
2. While the process is running on the server side, update the model values associated with the target part of the view on the client side respectivley.
3. When process ends on the server side, request a final update of the target part of the view  and stop polling on the client side.

In addition I just found something interesting, which may be an option for you also. Have a look at [PrimeFaces Push](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_6_0.pdf#page=584&zoom=auto,-239,774)

Comment: So is there a solution for this?

Comment: @Captai-N Updated answer.

Comment: Thanks but dosen't do the work. The problem is, that during the process is running, the poll is not firing until the response is done.

Comment: @Captai-N Not even if the request is made with AJAX and the poll is started on client side via JS? Hard to belive but what about doing processing on the server side in another thread? Thus response will be made immediatly, you just have to take care of an according thread communication to update the model values. Nevertheless, just be creative in how to do it. There is no standard way.

Comment: @Captai-N Updated answer again. Have a look at the last paragraph.